# Django views and templates, including Jinja2 and Mako, tutorials and resources

Tags: python, django, jinja2, mako

I'm new to Python and Django, but now have a pretty firm understanding of basic database and back end programming. However, I am finding it hard to learn the views and templates layers. I was wondering if anyone can suggest additional tutorials and resources, other than the official Django documentation.

I am also new to HTML, and am open to tutorials using Mako or Jinja2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We've been using Mako+Django for almost two years on a large project, and it's been great.  Mako is immensely better than the standard Django templates.  Why on Earth would I want to learn *another* templating language when I already have to know Python, Javascript, HTML, JQuery, etc.?  With Mako I can use regular Python, including all the libraries, in my HTML pages.  And with Django integrated on the back end, the templates stay simple.

You might want to look at my Django+Mako starter kit.  It does the templates the way I like to do them (not necessarily the standard way), but it is a project fully set up and ready to run.  You can start from it and customize.  http://warp.byu.edu/dist/django-mako.zip

**Update**: blog has moved to http://www.goalbrecht.com/2013/10/django-mako-plus-a-starter-kit/
and additional updates to the project are on [Django-Mako-Plus' Github](https://github.com/doconix/django-mako-plus).

Comment: I've been using your resultset.py recipe in ALL our Python website projects and I absolutely share your sentiments on templates.  We still use Spyce (still works great of course), but might try the Mako+Django route based on what you wrote on your blog.

Answer (score 0):

We use `Mako` in our workplace, and I highly recommend not using it. It's great for your own views, but if you want to use ANY third party libraries that include templates, they simply won't work.

Other than that, the official documentation, and googling for specific problems you're having is the best way to go when using django templating. Unfortunately, I can't comment on jinja templating.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I too started noticing that with Mako while reading some docs.